# Why ImageFont from PIL can't load Indonesia font in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I used `ImageFont from PIL` to load Indonesia Font shown in the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k0a0in932xo8p0u/AABGovbsBV_hsYwoKS8A1Srsa?dl=0).

The following command has `"OSError: cannot open resource"` error as

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, int(fontsize))
```

fontpath is the path to

```
Indonesia License Plate.ttf
```

inside the folder.

The error happened inside `ImageFont.py` at

```
self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine=layout_engine)
```

What is wrong with the font file?

Comment: Have no problem with `Indonesia License Plate.ttf`. Can you check other fonts?

Comment: Other fonts are ok using the same command.

Comment: Did you test using my font file?

Comment: May I see your API call?

Comment: Yes, I've used your file. The code is from your question.

Comment: Strange why I have that error?

Comment: Try using full path to font file

Comment: Do you use Python3 or Python2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192580/discussion-between-alderven-and-batuman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to upload and create ttf file again in this [page](https://font-converter.net/en).
Credit to the [PIL community](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues) for help.